# Pagination using joining multiple models

Tags: mysql, cakephp, pagination, cakephp-2.4

Each exam has one syllabus, each syllabus has one exam. So, I did this in the Exam model:

```
public $hasOne = 'Syllabuses'; //table: syllabuses, model: Syllabuses
```

From `UsersController` I did this:

```
public $uses = array('Setting', 'Exam', 'Syllabuses');
```

And in a method in `UsersController` I wanted to call paginate:

```
$options = array(
    'fields' => array('Exam.id', 'Exam.name', 'Syllabuses.id', 'Syllabuses.name', 'Syllabuses.syllabus', 'Syllabuses.last_updated'),
    'joins' => array(
        'table' => 'syllabuses',
        'conditions' => array('Exam.id = Syllabuses.exam_id')
    )
);
$this->paginate = $options;
$this->set('syllabuses', $this->Paginator->paginate('Syllabuses'));
```

exams table:

```
---+------+
id | name |
---+------+
```

and syllabuses table:

```
---+---------+------+----------+--------------+
id | exam_id | name | syllabus | last_updated |
---+---------+------+----------+--------------+
```

So, I got some error. Like this:

> Error: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'syllabuses Array LEFT JOIN `oes`.`syllabuses` AS `Syllabuses` ON (`Syllabuses`.`' at line 1

And my SQL that CakePHP prepared is:

```
SELECT `Exam`.`id`, `Exam`.`name`, `Syllabuses`.`id`, `Syllabuses`.`name`, `Syllabuses`.`syllabus`, `Syllabuses`.`last_updated` 
FROM `oes`.`exams` AS `Exam` syllabuses Array 
LEFT JOIN `oes`.`syllabuses` AS `Syllabuses` ON (`Syllabuses`.`exam_id` = `Exam`.`id`)
WHERE 1 = 1 LIMIT 20
```

But what I want is something like the query bellow. I have tested it in mysql:

```
SELECT  `Exam`.`id` AS eid,  `Exam`.`name` AS ename,  `Syllabuses`.`id` AS sid,  `Syllabuses`.`name` AS sname,  `Syllabuses`.`syllabus` ,  `Syllabuses`.`last_updated` 
FROM  `oes`.`syllabuses` AS  `Syllabuses` , exams AS Exam
WHERE Exam.id = Syllabuses.exam_id
ORDER BY Exam.id
LIMIT 20
```

Now anybody please help me achieve this. What kind of change can make CakePHP to prepare query like that(what I've tasted) to make my `Pagination` done.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I think this can be helpful for many programmers. That's why I want to share what I did finally:

```
$options = array(
    'fields' => array(
        'Exam.id',
        'Exam.name',
        'Syllabuses.id',
        'Syllabuses.name',
        'Syllabuses.exam_id',
        'Syllabuses.syllabus',
        'Syllabuses.last_updated'
    ),
    'recursive' => 0,
    'conditions' => array('Exam.id = Syllabuses.exam_id'),
    'limit' => 3
);
$this->paginate = $options;
$syllabuses = $this->Paginator->paginate('Exam');
```